# visual studio 2012 : list modified files before build

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'd like to list the modified files at before-build time, in order to increment various build numbers.
For example, if a javascript has been modified, I increment the client-code version number, 
if a cSharp file has been modified, I increment the server-code version number.

Do you know if there is a way to do it?

Thanks,

R.

Comment: Maybe you should use Git?

Comment: definitely, but I don't